# Looking for a formula to help sort out all possible combinations from a table in Excel/Sheets

Tags: multidimensional-array, excel-formula, datatable, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I don't even know if it is possible for a formula in sheets to do this, but I'm asking anyway.

I have a table of 18 people and 18 different 'jobs' to do on trips. I need to find all of the combinations of 4 people who cover most or all of the 18 jobs to select so each group of 4 is as self-sufficient as possible.

The people and their capabilities will change from time to time, so I'm trying to see if I can make a sheets or excel doc to help me automate or narrow down the combination process. Given that there are more than 3060 different combinations of people I could take on the trip, and how it's kind of hard for my (or most humans) brains to filter out the best combination, I was hoping to use the power of excel/sheets and it's formulas to make this a lot easier.

**Example:** 5x5 table instead of 18x18

|  | Ashley | Bobby | Carol | Douglas | Elizabeth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Can swim well enough for Lifeguard | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Can Fish for food effectively | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Can prepare a Fish and cook it | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Can tie secure complex knots | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Willing to drive for hours on end | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

**Desired Answer**: What kind of formula (or formulas) could help find all the possible combinations of 4 people with a 1 answer.

**What I've tried**: I've tried to brute force this by making a whole page of just copied and pasted combinations, offsetting each row by one to see what the total value at the end would be. But that... was proving to be far too time consuming.

I'm really hoping there's a formula to do what I tried to brute force.

Comment: A numerical, probably rather inefficient way to solve it is by random sampling groups of 4 many times and calculate via formula if a group covers all jobs. Then filter for those that do. See screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOZOS.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xzbjd.png) including the filter function. If that is an acceptable solution I'll write a full answer on it. (of course this 'solution' won't give all possible combinations)

Comment: Although, when trying it brute force, instead of random sampling you might as well calculate all 3060 combinations automatically (by auto generating sequences for the 4 individuals such that the sequences cover all possible combinations), and then filter for the groups that cover all jobs.

Comment: Interesting problem. I don't have formula-based approach to solve your problem. I did find some formulas that reduce the grunt work. Alt solution: use Google Apps Script. I detailed my solution [here](https://dogmatix.medium.com/all-possible-combinations-b8d67acf1d51)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not exactly what you are looking for, but I started down a rabbit hole I couldn't get out. I am not even going to attempt to break this down as there is probably a much better solution (Could not create a single cell formula due to the 50,000 character limit per cell...) but with these formula's, it will return the 4 best names in order to cover the most amount of work. Any ties will be randomly selected.

In essence, the most versatile person will be spot #1, then from the list of things they cannot do, the next best person will be selected, so on and so forth. The downside is obviously that you get one list of 4 names randomly and someone that cannot perform very many duties will never be selected (not sure how to account for that?).

Again, without a character limit you could compile all this into a single cell. In a new Sheet input the following:

**Cell A1**

```
=INDEX(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 >= "&LARGE(FILTER(BYCOL(Sheet1!A:Z, LAMBDA(x, SUM(x))),BYCOL(Sheet1!A:Z, LAMBDA(x, SUM(x))) <> 0),1)&"ORDER BY Col2 DESC"),RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTIF(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A:Z),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 >= "&LARGE(FILTER(BYCOL(Sheet1!A:Z, LAMBDA(x, SUM(x))),BYCOL(Sheet1!A:Z, LAMBDA(x, SUM(x))) <> 0),1)&"ORDER BY Col2 DESC"),"*")))
```

**Cell A2**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",A1&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",A1&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",A1&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",A1&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'"),"SELECT Col1,Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",A1&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",A1&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'")),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''")-1,1,2,1))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"ORDER BY Col2 DESC"),"SELECT Col1,Col2 WHERE Col2 >= "&LARGE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",A1&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",A1&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",A1&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",A1&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'"),"SELECT Col1,Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",A1&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",A1&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'")),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''")-1,1,2,1))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"ORDER BY Col2 DESC"),1)&"",0),RANDBETWEEN(1,QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",A1&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",A1&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",A1&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",A1&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'"),"SELECT Col1,Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",A1&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",A1&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'")),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''")-1,1,2,1))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&" ORDER BY Col2 DESC"),"ORDER BY Col2 DESC"),"SELECT Col2 WHERE Col2 >= "&LARGE(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",A1&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",A1&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",A1&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",A1&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'"),"SELECT Col1,Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",A1&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",A1&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'")),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''")-1,1,2,1))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&" ORDER BY Col2 DESC"),"ORDER BY Col2 DESC"),"SELECT Col2",0),1)&"",0),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''")),1),"All covered")
```

**Cell A3**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A2}&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A2}&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A2}&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A2}&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'"),"SELECT Col1,Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A2}&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A2}&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'")),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''")-1,1,2,1))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"ORDER BY Col2 DESC"),"SELECT Col1,Col2 WHERE Col2 >= "&LARGE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A2}&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A2}&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A2}&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A2}&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'"),"SELECT Col1,Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A2}&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A2}&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'")),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''")-1,1,2,1))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"ORDER BY Col2 DESC"),1)&"",0),RANDBETWEEN(1,QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A2}&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A2}&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A2}&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A2}&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'"),"SELECT Col1,Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A2}&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A2}&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'")),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''")-1,1,2,1))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&" ORDER BY Col2 DESC"),"ORDER BY Col2 DESC"),"SELECT Col2 WHERE Col2 >= "&LARGE(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A2}&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A2}&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A2}&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A2}&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'"),"SELECT Col1,Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A2}&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A2}&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'")),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''")-1,1,2,1))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&" ORDER BY Col2 DESC"),"ORDER BY Col2 DESC"),"SELECT Col2",0),1)&"",0),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''")),1),"All covered")
```

**Cell A4**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A3}&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A3}&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A3}&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A3}&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'"),"SELECT Col1,Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A3}&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A3}&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'")),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''")-1,1,2,1))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"ORDER BY Col2 DESC"),"SELECT Col1,Col2 WHERE Col2 >= "&LARGE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A3}&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A3}&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A3}&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A3}&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'"),"SELECT Col1,Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A3}&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A3}&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'")),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''")-1,1,2,1))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"ORDER BY Col2 DESC"),1)&"",0),RANDBETWEEN(1,QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A3}&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A3}&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A3}&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A3}&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'"),"SELECT Col1,Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A3}&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A3}&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'")),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''")-1,1,2,1))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&" ORDER BY Col2 DESC"),"ORDER BY Col2 DESC"),"SELECT Col2 WHERE Col2 >= "&LARGE(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A3}&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A3}&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A3}&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A3}&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'"),"SELECT Col1,Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({Sheet1!A1:Z},"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!1:1),1,1,1))&" WHERE Col1 <> '"&JOIN("' AND Col1 <> '",QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A3}&"'"))&"")),"SELECT Col1,"&"Col"&JOIN("+Col",SEQUENCE(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z),"SELECT "&"Col"&JOIN(",Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),1,2,1))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" OR Col1 = '",{A1:A3}&"'"))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&""),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 <> 0"))&"'")),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''")-1,1,2,1))&""),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''"),1,2,1))&" ORDER BY Col2 DESC"),"ORDER BY Col2 DESC"),"SELECT Col2",0),1)&"",0),"SELECT COUNT(Col1) LABEL COUNT(Col1)''")),1),"All covered")
```

**Sheet1**

[image: Sheet1]

**Sheet2**

[image: Sheet2]

The only requirements are that every row and column will require data, therefore a 1 or a 0 and a task. But it should be dynamic to allow for additional names and/or tasks.